# Is it possible to create a modified loop in java?

Tags: java, loops

I'm still new to Java and I want to know wether there is a way to create something like a custom loop? I would like to define repeat so I could pass in any block of code.
That means:

Calling function:

```
String str = "";
repeat(5) {
    str += "x";
}
```

and method structure:

```
public void repeat(int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        // e.g. str += "x"; (any block of code)
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is for a more complex method, but it is not allowed to paste the code here. But it is a similar structure needed.

Comment: Give it a try and you'll know if it works.. I recommend you to use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski I think you misunderstand the question. The OP wishes to somehow define `repeat` so he could pass in any block of code, from printing to the console to spamming Google with network requests. Just repeating a static block of code won't do.

Comment: @hexafraction Where you have all these details in the question?

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski It's something that must be assumed around the vague facts the OP provides. The syntax in the first block shows exactly what the OP asks, if one fills in the gaps.

Comment: @hexafraction I would prefer answering to the precise questions rather than answering to the question about which we can only 'assuming around the vague facts' In my opinion this one should be extended or closed.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski Sadly facts are not available, and I see neither the OP editing it, nor sufficient closevotes. Anyway, the first sample gives us enough to infer, as I see it. You can close or anwer *your* interpretation, as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not until Java 8. In Java 8, we'll have support for [things akin to lambdas/closures](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/) where we'll be able to pass in a *function* or snippet thereof instead of a primitive/object.  When Java 8 comes around, you can do as follows:

```
void repeat(int iter, Runnable r){
    for(int i=0; i<iter; i++){
        r.run();
    }
}
```

According to the lambda reference you'll be looking at something like:

```
repeat(5,  () -> { str += "x"; });
```

for the call.

Comment: this isn't how `Runnable` is supposed to be used, this is terrible advice!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson To that, I quote my own words, "I don't know why you'd want to do that with a runnable. You'll just create anonymous inner classes everywhere." Really the OP should wait until Java 8 before he even tries to do that.

Comment: Where does the OP ever mention `Runnable` in the question? As far as I can tell you are suggesting it and it is terrible advice and mis-use of an `Interface`.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Edited to use `Runnable` as a functional interface *a la* Java 8. It's a functional interface, hence accepts lambda.

Comment: Everyone should down vote this for this reason only. Straight from the JavaDoc. [***"The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread."***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) There is no threading or concurrency here, this is the wrong thing to be telling someone to do, no matter what the caveat, especially someone that doesn't know what they are doing to begin with.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson IMO the functional interface reason of it supersedes it. There is no `java.util.function` interface that works with `() -> void`. Notice that I am referring to Java 8's evaluation lambda-revision javadoc. If you can find another **functional** interface that has a `() -> void` lambda I'm all ears.

Comment: @hexafraction I think that the question has nothing to do with lambdas in Java, and with lambdas in general and you answer is misleading.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski I am explaining to the OP that the use of lambda is (IMO) a valid solution to his problem, the second Java 8 comes out. If you'd like to post a Java-7-targeting answer *by all means go ahead*.

Comment: +1 for the closest alternative available to what the OP was hoping to hear.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Actually `Runnable` will have to do unless the OP is going to waste time creating a technically-trivially-different interface that just has a void accepting no arguments, as otherwise no interface is available in the Java API that isn't specific to a UI, Executor, or other even more specific framework.

Comment: @hexafraction I am still thinking that this is the confusing answer because. 1. It is focused on lambdas in Java 8 (which is not even released), so I guess cannot be used by the author. 2. The problem can be solved without lambdas. 3. You are mentioning Runnable which makes your answer even more unclear. You could write of course simple answer (how to make it now) - and additionally how it could be make with lambdas proposed for java 8.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski Feel free to provide an answer. There is a solution for Java 7 but I personally oppose its use. Anyway, when you state that "3. You are mentioning Runnable which makes your answer even more unclear." that is because the lambda use requires an interface with one method that takes no args and returns void: the classic Runnable. It's all a runtime substitution in the end.

Comment: @hexafraction If you know a way to do it in Java 7, would you be so kind to post it here and tell why not to use it, so everyone can decide by himself how to use it. Also, if everyone knows how NOT to use it, he wouldn't find elsewhere this solution.

Comment: @Klicky It's the runnable that's been so graciously downvoted to potential oblivion :) . See post revision history.